# How to make each category a subsite?

Tags: subdomains

I have a WP site wp.domain.com, and want to make each category a subsite.

EG, foo.wp.domain.com would be a WP site that lists only posts in 
category 'foo', the search limits itself to category 'foo', the 
archives/etc are limited to 'foo'. There are no category archives 
unless foo has subcatgories.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

[You have got templates for this purpose:](http://codex.wordpress.org/images/1/18/Template_Hierarchy.png)

`category-{slug}.php` -> `category-{id}.php` -> `category.php`

Then link your subdomains to the different templates.